# How do I use paths with spaces in a Rake task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ruby, rakefile, albacore

I'm trying to create a rakefile for my ASP.Net application. This is the path for the mstest.exe file:

```
mstest = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"
```

This is part of the rakefile I have:

```
task :default do
      mstest = "C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"
      sh "#{mstest_file} \"#{testdll_file} "
end
```

I get this error:

> rake aborted!
>           Albacore::CommandNotFoundError: Command failed with status (127) - number 127 in particular means that the operating system could not find the executable:
>
> C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe

I think the spaces in the path cause the error: "Program Files (86x)/Visual Studio..." because if there is no space in the path, the rakefile works properly.

I have tried these things so far but have no successful results yet:

1. `mstest = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"`
2. `mstest = "C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"`
3. `mstest = "C:/Program\s Files\s (x86)/Microsoft\s Visual\s Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"`
4. `mstest = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\mstest.exe"`
5. Putting mstest and #{mstest} in single quotes, double quotes and combinations of those two.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using double-quotes with escaped spaces, instead of single quotes. Consider these:

```
"foo\ bar" # => "foo bar"
'foo\ bar' # => "foo\\ bar"
```

or:

```
"C:/Program Files\ (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe" 
# => "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"
'C:/Program Files\ (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe' 
# => "C:/Program Files\\ (x86)/Microsoft\\ Visual\\ Studio\\ 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"
```

Notice how the first, using double-quotes, is saying "use the literal character" when the interpreter encounters `"\ "`. Using single-quotes, it's saying "use backslash followed by a space", which you want to use since you want the backslash to propagate to the OS when you pass the string.

Really though, you probably should look at using Ruby's built-in [Shellwords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) class:

> Manipulates strings like the UNIX Bourne shell
>
> This module manipulates strings according to the word parsing rules of the UNIX Bourne shell.

In particular look at [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape):

> Escapes a string so that it can be safely used in a Bourne shell command line.

Consider this:

```
require 'shellwords'

'C:/Program Files\ (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe' 
# => "C:/Program Files\\ (x86)/Microsoft\\ Visual\\ Studio\\ 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"
Shellwords.escape("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe")
# => "C:/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/Microsoft\\ Visual\\ Studio\\ 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe"
```

Notice how `shellescape` escaped the parenthesis also.